# Operant Conditioning for reducing Rumination

Tags: cognitive-psychology, conditioning

Has operating conditioning been a useful tool for extinguishing rumination? If so, what is a typical training procedure for extinguishing rumination?

I'm looking for something like, first train the dolphin to touch it's nose to a stick, then train the command for XYZ using the stick to guide it.

Comment: generally animal-inspired psychology doesn't work too well for cognitive issues. It used to be en-vogue in the 1960s; see https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/what-happened-to-self-administered-aversion-therapy-with-a-rubber-band-in-parti

Comment: N.B. people tend to ask [this kind of question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cognitive-psychology+conditioning) with some regularity...